# Plotting using a CSV file

Tags: csv, graph, gnuplot

I have a csv file which has 5 entries on every row. Every entry is whether a network packet is triggered or not. The last entry in every row is the size of packet. Every row = time elapsed in ms.

e.g. row

```
1 , 0 , 1 , 2 , 117
```

How do I plot a graph for e.g. where x axis is the row number and y is the value for e.g. 1st entry in every row?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
set datafile separator ","
plot 'infile' using 0:1
```

Comment: @mgilson: "," is better yes, although "comma" is supported by Gnuplot 4.7.

Comment: So it is.  Depending on the machine I'm working on, I usually use 4.6 or even 4.4 since 4.7 is still in development.  But it's interesting that they added this.  I still keep it around for reference or special purposes however :).  I wonder if there are any subtle differences between `","` and `comma`.

Comment: @mgilson: I don't think there is any difference, `src/set.c:2386` reads `df_separator = ',';` and `src/set.c:2392` reads `df_separator = sep[0];` which in my eyes should be the same.

Comment: looks the same to me too based on your comment.  I've never really dug into the gnuplot source too much (maybe I should sometime).  Is it well organized?

Comment: @mgilson: Besides some whitespace annoyances it seems to be pretty readable, not that I've dug very far yet. I found the above lines by grepping for `"comma"` in `src/` :).

Comment: I jfst get invalid expression, doesn't seem to understand file paths for 'infile'

Comment: @JosephGarvin: you should replace `infile` with your csv file

Comment: Thanks!, never realized this has to be done!

Answer (score 17):

You can also plot to a png file using gnuplot (which is free):

terminal commands

```
gnuplot> set title '<title>'
gnuplot> set ylabel '<yLabel>'
gnuplot> set xlabel '<xLabel>'
gnuplot> set grid
gnuplot> set term png
gnuplot> set output '<Output file name>.png'
gnuplot> plot '<fromfile.csv>'
```

*note: you always need to give the right extension (.png here) at `set output`*

Then it is also possible that the ouput is not lines, because your data is not continues. To fix this simply change the 'plot' line to:

```
plot '<Fromfile.csv>' with line lt -1 lw 2
```

More line editing options (dashes and line color ect.) at:
http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_canvas/dashcolor.html

- gnuplot is available in most linux distros via the package manager (e.g. on an apt based distro, run `apt-get install gnuplot`)
- gnuplot is available in windows via Cygwin
- gnuplot is available on macOS via [homebrew](https://brew.sh) (run `brew install gnuplot`)

Comment: gnuplot is available on Windows without Cygwin.

Comment: You can download the native Windows installer or portable archive at https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplot/files/gnuplot/.