# How to plot a graph with linux?

Tags: linux, gnuplot

I want to plot a data file (`speed11.data`) in Linux. 
the data file looking like:

```
1,4.45823517e+01
2,4.45873528e+01
3,4.45923538e+01
4,4.45973549e+01
```

I used gnuplot, but I got error.

```
 gnuplot> plot "speed11.data"


gnuplot> 1,4.45823517e+01
         ^
         "speed11.data", line 1: invalid command
```

How to plot this graph?

The output of `locale` is:

```
LANG=en_CA.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Worked fine for me after replacing the commas with spaces.

Comment: I put tabs instead of ",", but I could not plot. gnuplot> 1      4.45823517e+01
         ^
         "speed13b.data", line 1: invalid command

Comment: All I can suggest is perhaps re-installing gnuplot.

Comment: Also please post version info. Ex: `uname -a && gnuplot --version && dpkg -l | grep "^i.*gnuplot"`

Comment: Also please post `gnuplot  <(echo "show terminal")`.

Comment: if you're created your data file or transfered it thru a Windows machine, likely it has `\r\n` line-endings. Use `dos2unix speed11.data` . Good luck.

Comment: @shellter: That's not true in general. On linux, gnuplot can read windows files with `\r\n`. However, it can not read Mac-files (`\r`). next point: gnuplot can also read files with commas as separators, use `set datafile separator ','` for this. And about the question: The error message is: invalid _command_, which occurs when doing `load "speed11.data"`. Maybe, gnuplot is defect and needs a reinstall. Or gnuplot is used the wrong way. Question: What are the exact (all) steps from starting a command line to entering the plot command?

Answer (score 1):

For gnuplot, you might want to look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14871272/plotting-using-a-csv-file) that deals with using comma separated values (CSV) in gnuplot.

Alternatively , you might want to try using [R](http://www.r-project.org/) instead of gnuplot. R has the ability to import csv data files and is able to do some sophisticated graphing.